# Unable to ping between two networks

Tags: networking

It might seem a rather basic question, so I would appreciate a elaborate explanation, as i was unable to find the desired answer on the internet.

[image]

I would like to ping and eventually telnet from S1 to S2.
I set RIPv2 routing but i am still unable to do so.

---

R1

```
Router>
Router>en
Router#show ru
Router#show running-config 
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 683 bytes
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
hostname Router
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
spanning-tree mode pvst
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip address 172.16.32.1 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
router rip
version 2
network 172.16.0.0
network 192.168.0.0
network 192.168.1.0
no auto-summary
ip classless
ip flow-export version 9
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
login
end
```

---

S0

```
Switch0>
Switch0>en
Switch0#show 
Switch0#show run
Switch0#show running-config 
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 1054 bytes
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption!
hostname Switch0
interface Vlan1
ip address 192.168.1.69 255.255.255.0
line con 0
line vty 0 4
login
line vty 5 15
login
end
```

---

S1

```
hostname Switch1
interface Vlan1
ip address 172.16.32.111 255.255.255.0
line con 0
line vty 0 4
login
line vty 5 15
login
```

Comment: You don't need RIP, or any other routing protocol, with a single router. Routing protocols do not route, they simply let routers exchange routing information. Routing is handled by the router's routing table, and the router will already have both networks in its routing table. The router, assuming routing is enabled (the default), will automatically route between the two networks. Without more information, e.g. router configuration, it is not possible to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah i thought so myself but again i was not sure where the problem might be. Tell me what device and what commands would you like output from. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Simply show the configurations of the devices, copy them, and paste them into the question.

Comment: Updated with running config

Comment: The switches have no Default Gateway configured. Without that they'll be limited to communication on their own respective networks only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to have any default gateway defined on either switch.

On S0:

```
ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
```

On S1:

```
ip default-gateway 172.16.32.1
```

In your case, the switches are simply hosts on the network. The IP addressing on a switch is simply for the switch management, and the switch management is a host, just like a PC or printer. A host gateway tells the host where to send traffic for destinations not on the same network.

Comment: @lcyuna, by the way, while this type of question is fine for [sf], it seems more directly on-topic for [networkengineering.se].

Comment: It there a way to manually transfer the topic there or only a moderator can do it ?

Comment: Only a moderator could migrate it, and you could flag it for migration, but it is also fine to be here. I'm simply suggesting that you could ask such things there, in the future. You can read the [help/on-topic] for each site to determine the best place for your questions.

Comment: I would also suggest you make good use of the interface configurations `description` command to explain to which device and interface that your interface connects. In this simple case, it is pretty obvious, but in more complex situations, it is not, and you need to use CDP or LLDP to make sure that you are configuring the correct interface. Also, if the answer solved your problem, you should accept it.